# How to bypass "enter SIM PIN" screen on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sim-card

The phone can't be accessed before PIN code is entered, the only alternative method is to remove the SIM card entirely. I haven't found a key combination that works on this version of Android.
Enter SIM PIN screen on Android 6.0.1:

[image]

Comment: same question for PUK request. How to use phone with Wifi only while waiting for the PUK/PIN.

Answer (score 2):

Why not enter the PIN to access the phone.  Well, I don't think you can bypass that.  If its your SIM, I would advise you contact your service provider and they would help.

Comment: Not an answer. I asked for a bypass, I don't know the PIN code.